# error_code":401 when give chat_id

Tags: telegram-bot

I am trying to get my chat_id for my telegram channel. Bot I get this line error:

```
 {"ok":false,"error_code":401,"description":"[Error]: Unauthorized"}
```

My Channel Name is: `MyName`

My link is: https://telegram.me/MyNameIsChannel.

Answer (score 4):

The first and the main reason of the problem is that I'm using my telegram on a phone only and have to type the token manually on a Laptop keyboard. That was the case. No firewalls, no extra installation (of some software) was a reason but a SIMPLE TYPO. Better just COPY&PASTE the token whatever way you can.

Don't forget about the "bot" suffix and upper/lowercase letters also do matter.

I've spent so many time for googling/troubleshooting and in fact it was a simple typo.

Comment: Thanks man! It was an O letter written as 0

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you aren't passing your bot's token to the query.
If your channel is public with username @MyNameIsChannel and your bot's token is AAAAA, then you should make this request to find out channel's id (just send any message and watch `chat_id` in reply JSON):

`https://api.telegram.org/bot147772105:AAEGOblbPGiU9Hfoy7wVFt0bVfJsdO3iis4/sendMessage?text=Hello&chat_id=@MyNameIsChannel`

Please check beforehand that your bot is admin of that channel.

Answer (score 2):

Try obtaining the ID of this channel. Usually, the API requires the ID of the channel as string.

https://api.telegram.org/bot147772105:AAEGOblbPGiU9Hfoy7wVFt0bVfJsdO3iis4/sendMessage?test=Hello&chat_id=YourIDhere

Would become

https://api.telegram.org/bot147772105:AAEGOblbPGiU9Hfoy7wVFt0bVfJsdO3iis4/sendMessage?test=Hello&chat_id=-123456789123

(Most channels and groups have a - sign at the beginning. Make sure you'll copy it to make it work nicely.)